# Why was my answer deleted and then duplicated as a comment?

Tags: support, deletion, specific-answer

My answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531705/boundary-of-a-set/531728#531728) has been deleted by a moderator, apparently, and made into a comment. I would like to know why, as I cannot see a good reason for it.

The OP asked for a hint, and that's exactly what I gave. In what sense is that a comment and not an answer?

Comment: Nine downvotes and still no one explains to me why it was a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Originally your answer read (and what I converted into a comment was)

> As you said yourself, the set you are looking for has empty interior.

which in my opinion was neither an answer or a hint, but simply a restatement of something the OP mentioned in the question.   But, fine, I'll undelete it and let the community handle it.

Comment: Fine, from now on I'll write "hint:" whenever I give a hint.

Comment: Hint: be extra polite to the moderators!

Comment: Sometimes the conversion of an answer to a comment can be beneficial. For example, when the answer gets a large number of downvotes.